# How to set an Ionic list item height with a background image

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

In Ionic, I am trying to show a list of items, each with a background image.

I am trying to increase the height, but my current solution only increases the blank space, and does not show more of the background image:

[image]

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item back-img="{{post.image.url}}" ui-sref="app.post({id:post.ID})" ng-repeat="post in data.posts" ng-style="{'height': '250px'}" >
            {{post.title}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

```
.directive('backImg', function(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        var url = attrs.backImg;
        var content = element.find('a');
        content.css({
            'background': 'url(' + url +')',
            'background-size' : 'cover'
        });
    };
```

How can I set the list item height in a way that the background image for each row is fully shown?

(I assume I would have to set the background-CSS on the container, not the anchor? How?)

Comment: `background-size: contain;` will make the image always go inside. but this could/ usually doest stretches the image all over the place.

Comment: Hmm, `contain` scales small and repeats the image multiple times from left to right, but keeps the (wrong) height.

Comment: Yh contain was probably not what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by using "line-height" instead of "height":

```
ng-style="{'line-height': '250px'}"
```

Although this does not allow for wrapping longer text.

Comment: use `.item-text-wrap` like [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#cards)

Answer (score 1):

Line height will be dependent on the text. 
You can add min-height, It should work too :

```
ng-style="{'min-height':'250px'}"
```